# Display picture based on UDP message

Tags: python, tkinter, udp

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to write a program that display image on an interface based on a received UDP message.
While I can do the two things separately I can't make it work together.
The reason is simple, the while loop of the UDP listener does not allow the tkinter's mainloop to happen and I can't find a way to make it work.
I'm also not sure about the image "delete" side of the code.

Can you help me to find the solution ?

Not sure if this is important but this is running on a Raspberry Pi.

Here is the code:
    from tkinter import *
    import socket

```
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

UDP_PORT = 11000
UDP_IP = ""

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

photo1 = PhotoImage(file="test.gif")
photo2 = PhotoImage(file="ant.gif")

canvas.create_image(25, 25, image=photo1)

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    if data.decode() == "on":
        canvas.create_image(100, 125, image=photo2)
    elif data.decode() == "off":
        canvas.delete(photo2)

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you so much.
Vince.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want 2 things to happen at the same time you need to run 2 threads. The python `threading` module makes this very easy.

```
from threading import Thread

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

UDP_PORT = 11000
UDP_IP = ""

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

photo1 = PhotoImage(file="test.gif")
photo2 = PhotoImage(file="ant.gif")

canvas.create_image(25, 25, image=photo1)

def listen_for_udp():
    while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        if data.decode() == "on":
            canvas.create_image(100, 125, image=photo2)
        elif data.decode() == "off":
            canvas.delete(photo2)

t = Thread(target=listen_for_udp)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

root.mainloop()
```

(totally untested)

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. It is working great now with threads. I just edit your solution to add the two missing Imports (my bad, they were out of the code section on my original email.

Comment: Just one last thing... The "canvas.delete" side of it does not work. I can add the image but cannot remove it.  Any idea? Thanks